# __DEV__ is not defined running expo av video on react project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, expo-av

Im' trying to display a video using expo-av video everything fine when i use html video i have then install expo-av and expo-av-modules and when i go back to my localhost front end it show a white page with this error message

Uncaught ReferenceError: **DEV** is not defined
at ./node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/sweet/setUpErrorManager.fx.js (setUpErrorManager.fx.ts:5:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/index.js (UnavailabilityError.ts:9:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:24:1)
at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
at ./node_modules/expo-asset/build/Asset.js (events.js:497:1)
at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)

I have google this error and none of the solution provided work in my case

It's a classic react project that i display on browser before to compile to apps with ionic.
Am i missing something is expo-av compatible with my case does it only work in android or ios simulator ??

Comment: Did you solve it? Faced the same issue...